# Geofencing and Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, geofencing

I want to create a geofencing app with android 5.0 (Lollipop).
But as I go through this google link http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
i realized that google uses the LocationClient class which has been deprecated. 
So my question is, 
how do I get geofencing updates with the GoogleApiClient?

here is the code that I need to replace:

```
 mLocationClient.addGeofences( 
                    mCurrentGeofences, pendingIntent, this);
```

mLocationClient is from LocationClient class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```